# Sent assets on Ethereum to a zkSync Safe address

Tags: safe-core

I've sent assets on the Ethereum network instead of on the zksync network to the address of my zksync based Safe.

I have the following
SafeProxyFactory 1.3.0
SafeL2 1.3.0

Is there any way to recover the assets or are my assets permanently gone?

Kind regards
Barista

Comment: If you've mistakenly sent assets meant for the zkSync network to an Ethereum address, unfortunately, retrieving those assets can be challenging. Ethereum and zkSync operate on different networks with distinct addresses, and transactions made on one network cannot directly be recovered or accessed on the other.

Comment: @CanardCoca  If and when the zkEVM reaches parity with the EVM, the address derivation will be updated to match Ethereum and the same bytecode will have the same address on both chains, deployed bytecodes to different addresses on zkSync could then be deployed to the same the Ethereum-matching addresses on zkSync"
Does this make sense? any chance this will happen in the future?

Answer (score 0):

For now, since ZkSync and the EVM differ in how they calculate addresses, this is not possible. I haven't see any news of ZkSync converging to the same derivation method used in the EVM, so unless they do, I am afraid this will remain not possible.

Hope it helps, Louis